# How to develop .net core library (code) and provide to third party vendors to develop their applications in Windows/Mac/Linux

Tags: .net-core, cross-platform

We have product of our organization which we have developed in .net 4.5 (c#). Now we provide this solution in the form of library (.dll) to our vendors (partners) who develop client facing applications.

Here we have our product (SDK) developed in .net, Java and iOs (mobile SDK). As per client OS and requirement we provided any of solution.

Now we want to develop the same in .net core as it is platform independent.

My question is how I can create .net core library and provide the same to our vendors so that they can use the same and develop the cross platform applications OR as per client facing requirement. But here our solution would be only one i.e. .net core lib instead of multiple SDKs of .net, java or iOS

Please suggest, as i couldn't see the option to publish .net core library as self contained.

Comment: Sounds like you still need to go over the basics, https://blog.lextudio.com/which-class-library-project-to-go-in-visual-studio-2015-2017-a48710cf3dff

Comment: Thanks for link @LexLi. You mean to say that we have to develop our library in .net standard and our vendors have to consume it by using .net core and then it can run on various supported platforms.

Comment: It depends on what exactly your vendors want. .NET Standard class libraries of course are the best options, but if they only need .NET Core class libraries, you can do that also.